# Anaconda Python Index Name Error

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am facing a problem in Anaconda.

Whenever I close a file in `jupyter notebook` and open it again and run a command,it says numpy is not defined. But it is already defined in the start.
That command becomes line number 1.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you ran that cell that imports numpy.?

Comment: That says *arr* is not defined, not numpy.

Comment: The numbers on the left don't update dynamically. You may have restarted your kernel in between. Run all your commands in a single cell to test. And don't show built-in `list`, use `lst` instead.

Comment: i have restarted my environment. It does not matter. Do i have to run each line again to get specific result from my required line?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I have to run all of my code first by going to the cell and press run all.
After that i can go edit any code and run it again, it will not give me any kind of error.
Thanks guys